# Append custom code to UI events

Tags: python, scripting, interface

is there any way to extend Blender UI behavior executing custom code when user interacts with it?

Les's say I wanted to change some rendering option when I select a different view layer, can I capture the interaction event I had with the Outliner Editor and run my script to update rendering options?

I already created an addon to store/retrieve rendering settings for each view layer, but I'd like this to happen automatically when I select the view layer.